# Dropwizard:"error processing your request" for retriving data from database

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard

When i tries to open

```
http://localhost:8080/tailor/orders
```

which should return all the orders in database.but it's generating error

```
{"message":"There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID fe49a13e76c59894)."}
```

I'm unable to trace the problem what's causing this.

I'm using dropwizard for restful web service and hibernate from dropwizard for sqlight database.

Class:

Resources class:

```
@Path("/tailor")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TailorResource {

OrderDAO orderdao;

public TailorResource(OrderDAO odao) {
    this.orderdao = odao;
}


@GET
@Path("/orders")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<OrderModel> getAllOrders() {
    return orderdao.findAll();
}

@GET
@Path("/orders/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public OrderModel getOrderById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return orderdao.findById(id);
}
}
```

OrderDAO class:

```
public class OrderDAO extends AbstractDAO<OrderModel>{


 public OrderDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super(sessionFactory);
}

  public OrderModel findById(int id) {
   return get(id);
}

public OrderModel create(OrderModel o) {
    return persist(o);
}

public List<OrderModel> findAll() {
    return list(namedQuery("com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.OrderModel.findAll"));
}}
```

Order Class:

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(
    name = "com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.OrderModel.findAll",
    query = "SELECT o FROM OrderModel o"
),
@NamedQuery(
    name = "com.yammer.dropwizard.tailor.model.OrderModel.findById",
    query = "SELECT o FROM OrderModel o WHERE o.ID = :ID"
)
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "Order")
public class OrderModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "o_id")
int ID;

@Column(name = "o_shirt_quantity")
int shirtQuantity;
@Column(name = "o_longshirt_quantity")
int longshirtQuantity;
@Column(name = "o_trouser_quantity")
int trouserQuantity;
@Column(name = "o_coat_quantity")
int coatQuantity;
@Column(name = "o_deliverydate")
Date deliveryDate;
@Column(name = "o_orderdate")
Date orderDate;
@Column(name = "o_shirt_price")
Double shirtPrice;
@Column(name = "o_longshirt_price")
Double longshirtPrice;
@Column(name = "o_trouser_price")
Double trouserPrice;
 @Column(name = "o_coat_price")
Double coatPrice;
@Column(name = "o_totalamount")
Double totalAmount;
@Column(name = "o_discount")
Double discount;
@Column(name = "o_advancedpayment")
Double advancedPayment;
@Column(name = "o_remainingpayment")
Double remainingPayment;
@Column(name = "o_orderstatus")
int orderStatus;
}
```

Database configuration class:

```
public class databaseConfiguration extends Configuration {

@Valid
@NotNull
@JsonProperty
DataSourceFactory dbconfigurations = new DataSourceFactory();

public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
    //return dbconfigurations;
    Map<String,String> s=new HashMap<String,String>();
    s.put("hibernate.dialect","Hibernate.SQLightDialect.SQLiteDialect");
    dbconfigurations.setProperties(s);
    return dbconfigurations;
}
}
```

Main service Class:

```
public class TailorApplication extends Application<databaseConfiguration> {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new TailorApplication().run(args);
}

private final HibernateBundle<databaseConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<databaseConfiguration>(CustomerModel.class) {
     {
    @Override
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(databaseConfiguration configuration) {
        return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
    }
};

@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<databaseConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bootstrap.addBundle(hibernate);

}

@Override
public void run(databaseConfiguration configuration, Environment environment)
        throws Exception {

      final OrderDAO odao = new OrderDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory());

    environment.jersey().register(new TailorResource(odao));
}

}
```

YML file:

```
dbconfigurations:
# the name of your JDBC driver
driverClass: org.sqlite.JDBC

# the username
user:

# the password
password:

url: jdbc:sqlite:TailorDB.db
```

Help please?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the logs for the database?

Comment: how to do that??where will be the log file.new to all this

Comment: We don't even know which database you are using. But read those docs and I'm sure you will find the log files.

Comment: I'm using sqlight for database

Comment: added YML file in post.

Comment: ERROR [2014-01-21 10:40:52,133] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapp
er: Error handling a request: 48a0447f00533ec9
! org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution cont
ext

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you filled the application class with the entities:

```
private final HibernateBundle<AppConfiguration> hibernateBundle = new HibernateBundle<AppConfiguration>(
            //
            //
            //ADD ENTITIES HERE
            //
            //
            Person.class
            ,Product.class
            ) {
        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(
                AppConfiguration configuration) {
            return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

1. On the face of it, looks like you have missed the @UnitOfWork annotation on getAllOrders.
2. Having said that, the error you have shared is the external messaging that DW provides by default. Instead you should look at your web service logs for the exact error and precise stacktrace. If you run your service in terminal with java -jar path/to/shaded.jar server my.yml you should see elaborate error on the console. Please share that so that community can help better.